# PDO Microsoft Access

Tags: php, database, linux, connection, pdo

I am running **linux** from bluehost and have PDO installed.
I wish to access *.mdb info, however I cannot seem to get past the connection string for PDO in this case.

```
$dbh = new PDO("odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};Dbq=$mdb;Uid=Admin");
```

Generates error:
SQLSTATE[IM002] SQLDriverConnect: 0 [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified

I know the the path is correct:
/home1/[Removed]/pss/pss.md

Does anyone know of any solution to this issue using the PDO library?

Comment: permissions (access to file system) issue?

Comment: Unless I've missed something, PDO only supports MDB on Windows (and maybe Mac with Office)

Comment: @PhilLello  If you have a possible solution, please add it as an answer not a comment. Otherwise I do not know how to give you credit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As requested, expanding on my comment.

MDB support on Linux is limited; although [MDB Tools](http://mdbtools.sourceforge.net/) (used by PDO on Linux) does provide partial read-only support, the general status seems far from production ready, as the [FAQ](http://mdbtools.sourceforge.net/faq.html) says

> 1.2 What does MDB Tools do
>
> MDB Tools is an open source suite of libraries and utilities to read
>   (and soon write) MDB database files.
>
> 1.6 Is there a roadmap?
>
> Roughly, the plan moving forward looks like this.
>
> - Add index scan capability to libmdb and the SQL engine with a query
>     plan generator.
> - Add support for adding rows to existing tables and an mdb-import
>     tool.
> - Add full write support to libmdb and libmdbsql.
> - Extract queries, table properties, VBA script, forms.
> - mdb-check database consistancy checker and recovery tool.
> - Add joins.
> - Ability to add tables.

If you only need to read the .mdb, then installing mdbtools might be good enough.

If you need read-write, or any of the features on the roadmap, and must use .mdb, then use a Windows or *possibly* Mac host

If the .mdb is just a datasource, export it to SQL and use MySQL or PostGres (PostGres seems to have better ODBC support for Windows, if this is relevant to your project)

Comment: Amazing Response! I am converting .mdb to .sql and custom importing as the table names seem to be pseudo random.